# jQuery JavaScript Encoding HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How on earth do you encode HTML with jQuery/JavaScript?

Havn't found any working solution after hours of Googling and surfing this site.

This:

```
jQuery('<div/>').text(value).html();
```

does not work with jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "encode"?

If you mean something similar to PHP's htmlentities, your solution should work with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrH8b/

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BEztG/), make sure you're using that to *get* the encoded text.

If your goal is to encode it for transmission (e.g. a POST), you should be looking at [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%3aGlobal_Functions%3aencodeURIComponent) instead, for example:

```
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(value);
```